# Dúvidas em conveter funções VB6 para PHP

Tags: php, visual-basic-6

Preciso repassar alguns códigos de VB6 para PHP porém estou com uma dúvida do que este código faz:

```
Private Function SomarValor(v As String) As Double
Dim x As Byte, resultado As Double
For x = 1 To Len(v)
resultado = resultado + CDbl(Mid(v, x, 1))
Next
SomarValor = resultado
End Function
```

Esta função `SomarValor()` recebe valores como `0202827610`, se alguém puder ajudar.

Já tentei procurar o significado destas funções internas como `CDbl`, `Mid`, mas não consegui entender.

Comment: Sim é possível o `mid()` é um equivalmente ao `substr()`

Comment: certo, mas o que isto aqui faz `For x = 1 To Len(v)` e esta função **"CDbl"**, saberia me explicar, por gentileza?

Comment: Se entendi certo, ele lê `0202827610` caracter por caracter e vai somando o resultado.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O código recebe uma string `0202827610` é feito um `for` que extrai um caracter dessa string como [mid()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/05e63829(v=vs.90).aspx) e tem seu valor convertido para double com [CDbl()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ftekwwt0(v=vs.84).aspx) que por último vai somando o valor.

Uma forma de converter esse código para o PHP seria assim:

```
$str = '0202827610';

$arr = str_split($str);
$total = 0;
foreach($arr as $item){
    $total += $item;
}

echo $total;
```

Basicamente o `str_plit()` transformar a string em um array e ele é iterado e somado dentro do foreach.

Comment: Perfeito amigo, obrigado. Nunca tive contato com VB6 então estava perdido no que isto ali fazia. Obrigado!